# a tag toUpperCase comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given:

```
<div>
  <span><a href="#">abc</a></span>
  <span><a href="#">def</a></span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do a string comparison with toUpperCase() between a given string value and the link text (as shown above in the span collection) and if it doesn't match hide the span? Anyway to incorporate "contains" in the mix?

Thanks,

rod.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/toUpperCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following. But keep in mind this will run for all `a` tags within a `span`. You should modify it will a `id` on your `div` or some kind of `class` attribute.

```
$('span a').each(function() {
  var anchor = $(this);
  if (anchor.text().toUpperCase() == 'ABC') {
    anchor.hide();
  }
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/KCCVm/